# Apply parent window's css variables to iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a parent window and an iframe.

In the parent window's `html`, I have a list of CSS variables:

```
:root {
  --lp-font-size-heading-lg: 2.5rem;
  --lp-font-size-heading-md: 2rem;
  --lp-font-size-heading-sm: 1.5rem;
}
```

but these variables are not available in the iframe, i.e.
in iframe's header, I have:

```
font-size: var(--lp-font-size-heading-md);
```

but iframe cannot find the definition of `--lp-font-size-heading-md`

How to add the CSS variables in the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is copy the variables from the outer iFrame into the inner iFrame one by one once the iFrame is available:

```
    const iframeDocumentElement = document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.document.documentElement;
    const fontLarge = document.documentElement.getPropertyValue('--lp-font-size-heading-lg');
    const fontMedium = document.documentElement.getPropertyValue('--lp-font-size-heading-md');
    iframeDocumentElement.style.setProperty('--lp-font-size-heading-lg', fontLarge);
    iframeDocumentElement.style.setProperty('--lp-font-size-heading-md', fontMedium);
```